# Class/function in python where each value assigned an increasing unique number

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a data structure/function in Python where each value called is assigned an increasing "id" number

Specifically, the first value entered (e.g., "a") would get id value 0, the next (e.g., "b") would get id 1, and if an earlier one is used (e.g "a" again) it would get the original value (i.e. 0))

At the moment i use the following code, but wondered if it may be a built-in function for this.

```
maximum_number, all_id_numbers = 0, {}
def return_increasing_id(word):
    global maximum_number
    try:
        return(all_id_numbers[word])
    except KeyError:
        all_id_numbers[word] = maximum_number
        maximum_number = maximum_number +1
        return(all_id_numbers[word])
```

Comment: You mean like a list?

Comment: @jonrsharpe A list wouldn't have a O(1) lookup time though.

Comment: @Rawing not by word, no, but it does by index/id; I guess that's the trade off.

Comment: You could remove the `maximum_number` variable and use `len(all_id_numers)` instead. (Assuming you never remove any items from the dict.) That should increase the legibility of this code by a significant bit.

Comment: The short answer is no, that isn't built in as written. If you want `O(1)` lookup of ID by word, a dictionary is the way to do it. You could use `itertools.count` as the source of IDs, though, and maybe write a class implementing `MutableMapping` to make this more reusable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use defaultdict with your own function passed to it to clean things up a bit.

EDIT thanks to @Rawing. It's very clean now!

EDIT2 thanks to @JonClements it is now a one-liner

CODE:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count

d = defaultdict(lambda n=count(): next(n))

print(d['a'])
print(d['b'])
print(d['c'])

print(d['a'])
print(d['b'])
print(d['c'])
```

OUTPUT:

```
0
1
2
0
1
2
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `defaultdict(itertools.count().__next__)`.

Comment: I'd go for: `d = defaultdict(lambda n=count(): next(n))` instead of `__next__` as depending on Python version, that might have to be `.next()` instead...

Comment: @JonClements wow, that's awesome. You should make this into an answer to be accepted

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a simple list, and the index as the ID. That way the id is guaranteed to be unique and it's "increasing" like you wanted. I don't see why you'd give yourself headaches trying to make your own ID assignment logic, which could introduce more bugs into your code.

edit: lookup time for a list by index is actually O(1), see: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: Lists can convert an index to an object in O(1) time, but _finding_ the index of an object takes O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

The Python 3 tutorial, [section 3.1.3](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) introduces the List data type as:

> Python knows a number of compound data types, used to group together
>   other values. The most versatile is the list, which can be written as
>   a list of comma-separated values (items) between square brackets.

When you create a list in your code what you add a value to a position in a sequence which acts as a key. The dictionary data type, what you are using in your question, lets you assign a key explicitly.

If you would like to create a dictionary of words with the count of appearances in a corpus of text see the example below.

```
sentence = 'The quick brown fox jumps the brown log'
for word in sentence[i].split(" "):
            word_dict[word] += 1

word_dict = {
 'The': 1, 'quick': 1,  'brown': 2, 'fox': 1,
 'jumps': 1,  'the': 1, 'log': 1}
```

While creating a function to push words in a dictionary and increment the counter is a good start, you may want to check out a tutorial for [Bag of Words models on Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/details/part-1-for-beginners-bag-of-words). The tutorial provides a great overview of other techniques to use when processing text.